# Upload image using javascript 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image upload box like this, which is a part of submission form.

```
<li id="field_1_14" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label">Ảnh</label><div class="gfield_description">Ảnh hàng hóa bạn muốn mua hộ</div><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_fileupload"><div id="gform_multifile_upload_1_14" data-settings="{&quot;runtimes&quot;:&quot;html5,flash,html4&quot;,&quot;browse_button&quot;:&quot;gform_browse_button_1_14&quot;,&quot;container&quot;:&quot;gform_multifile_upload_1_14&quot;,&quot;drop_element&quot;:&quot;gform_drag_drop_area_1_14&quot;,&quot;filelist&quot;:&quot;gform_preview_1_14&quot;,&quot;unique_names&quot;:true,&quot;file_data_name&quot;:&quot;file&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/?gf_page=5c28261389c3423&quot;,&quot;flash_swf_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.flash.swf&quot;,&quot;silverlight_xap_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.silverlight.xap&quot;,&quot;filters&quot;:{&quot;mime_types&quot;:[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Allowed Files&quot;,&quot;extensions&quot;:&quot;jpg,gif,png,pdf&quot;}],&quot;max_file_size&quot;:&quot;2097152b&quot;},&quot;multipart&quot;:true,&quot;urlstream_upload&quot;:false,&quot;multipart_params&quot;:{&quot;form_id&quot;:1,&quot;field_id&quot;:14,&quot;_gform_file_upload_nonce_1&quot;:&quot;8b58601a9a&quot;},&quot;gf_vars&quot;:{&quot;max_files&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;gform_multifile_messages_1_14&quot;,&quot;disallowed_extensions&quot;:[&quot;php&quot;,&quot;asp&quot;,&quot;aspx&quot;,&quot;cmd&quot;,&quot;csh&quot;,&quot;bat&quot;,&quot;html&quot;,&quot;hta&quot;,&quot;jar&quot;,&quot;exe&quot;,&quot;com&quot;,&quot;js&quot;,&quot;lnk&quot;,&quot;htaccess&quot;,&quot;phtml&quot;,&quot;ps1&quot;,&quot;ps2&quot;,&quot;php3&quot;,&quot;php4&quot;,&quot;php5&quot;,&quot;php6&quot;,&quot;py&quot;,&quot;rb&quot;,&quot;tmp&quot;]}}" class="gform_fileupload_multifile" style="position: relative;">
                                        <div id="gform_drag_drop_area_1_14" class="gform_drop_area" style="position: relative;">
                                            <span class="gform_drop_instructions">Drop files here or </span>
                                            <input id="gform_browse_button_1_14" type="button" value="Select files" class="button gform_button_select_files" aria-describedby="extensions_message" tabindex="4" style="z-index: 1;">
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="html5_1ad7o2aq0k8310031upe1gkr1lqf3_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 27px; left: 550px; width: 136px; height: 34px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1ad7o2aq0k8310031upe1gkr1lqf3" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,image/gif,.gif,image/png,.png,application/pdf,.pdf"></div></div><span id="extensions_message" class="screen-reader-text">Accepted file types: jpg, gif, png, pdf.</span><div class="validation_message">
                                <ul id="gform_multifile_messages_1_14">
                                </ul>
                            </div></div><div id="gform_preview_1_14"></div></li>
```

When user upload an image test.png by drag/drop or select image from his computer, it will upload the image to server, and the image upload box become like this

```
<li id="field_1_14" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label">Ảnh</label><div class="gfield_description">Ảnh hàng hóa bạn muốn mua hộ</div><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_fileupload"><div id="gform_multifile_upload_1_14" data-settings="{&quot;runtimes&quot;:&quot;html5,flash,html4&quot;,&quot;browse_button&quot;:&quot;gform_browse_button_1_14&quot;,&quot;container&quot;:&quot;gform_multifile_upload_1_14&quot;,&quot;drop_element&quot;:&quot;gform_drag_drop_area_1_14&quot;,&quot;filelist&quot;:&quot;gform_preview_1_14&quot;,&quot;unique_names&quot;:true,&quot;file_data_name&quot;:&quot;file&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/?gf_page=5c28261389c3423&quot;,&quot;flash_swf_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.flash.swf&quot;,&quot;silverlight_xap_url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/localhost\/wp-includes\/js\/plupload\/plupload.silverlight.xap&quot;,&quot;filters&quot;:{&quot;mime_types&quot;:[{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Allowed Files&quot;,&quot;extensions&quot;:&quot;jpg,gif,png,pdf&quot;}],&quot;max_file_size&quot;:&quot;2097152b&quot;},&quot;multipart&quot;:true,&quot;urlstream_upload&quot;:false,&quot;multipart_params&quot;:{&quot;form_id&quot;:1,&quot;field_id&quot;:14,&quot;_gform_file_upload_nonce_1&quot;:&quot;8b58601a9a&quot;},&quot;gf_vars&quot;:{&quot;max_files&quot;:&quot;10&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;gform_multifile_messages_1_14&quot;,&quot;disallowed_extensions&quot;:[&quot;php&quot;,&quot;asp&quot;,&quot;aspx&quot;,&quot;cmd&quot;,&quot;csh&quot;,&quot;bat&quot;,&quot;html&quot;,&quot;hta&quot;,&quot;jar&quot;,&quot;exe&quot;,&quot;com&quot;,&quot;js&quot;,&quot;lnk&quot;,&quot;htaccess&quot;,&quot;phtml&quot;,&quot;ps1&quot;,&quot;ps2&quot;,&quot;php3&quot;,&quot;php4&quot;,&quot;php5&quot;,&quot;php6&quot;,&quot;py&quot;,&quot;rb&quot;,&quot;tmp&quot;]}}" class="gform_fileupload_multifile" style="position: relative;">
                                        <div id="gform_drag_drop_area_1_14" class="gform_drop_area" style="position: relative;">
                                            <span class="gform_drop_instructions">Drop files here or </span>
                                            <input id="gform_browse_button_1_14" type="button" value="Select files" class="button gform_button_select_files" aria-describedby="extensions_message" tabindex="4" style="z-index: 1;">
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="html5_1ad7o2aq0k8310031upe1gkr1lqf3_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 186px; width: 136px; height: 34px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1ad7o2aq0k8310031upe1gkr1lqf3" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,image/gif,.gif,image/png,.png,application/pdf,.pdf"></div></div><span id="extensions_message" class="screen-reader-text">Accepted file types: jpg, gif, png, pdf.</span><div class="validation_message">
                                <ul id="gform_multifile_messages_1_14"></ul>
                            </div></div><div id="gform_preview_1_14"><div id="o_1ad7oetmvfm31gsd11lhsoc1s88f" class="ginput_preview"><img class="gform_delete" src="http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/delete.png" onclick="gformDeleteUploadedFile(1,14, this);" alt="Delete this file" title="Delete this file" scale="0"> <strong>test.jpg</strong></div></div></li>
```

And I found this part of code in form submission, above submit button

```
<input type="hidden" name="gform_uploaded_files" id="gform_uploaded_files_1" value="{&quot;input_14&quot;:[{&quot;temp_filename&quot;:&quot;ff301078_input_14_o_1ad7pjak2psd8g4fhpi71ajia.jpg&quot;,&quot;uploaded_filename&quot;:&quot;test.jpg&quot;}]}">
```

Instead of letting user to upload image like above, I want to:

1. Hide the image upload box using CSS (DONE!)
2. Use javascript to upload the "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/myimage.jpg" to that image box.

myimage.jpg is already on server and can publicly access.

Can anybody please help me to do step (2)?

As a result ,when user click form submit button, the image that user actually submit is myimage.jpg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is set a image to the box programatically and not let the User upload it. Then you can just use Jquery and set the `src` of the image.

```
var imageSrc = "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/myimage.jpg";

var imageHolder = '<img class="gform_delete" src="'+ imageSrc +'" alt="Delete this file" title="Delete this file" scale="0"><strong>test.jpg</strong>';

$('#gform_preview_1_14').append(imageHolder); // once you append the HTML image will be accessed from the server and loaded.
```

Comment: i think that will only modify the preview image before upload, the image which is uploaded is still test.png. I think there is something need to be done with <input type="hidden" name="gform_uploaded_files" id="gform_uploaded_files_1" value="{&quot;input_14&quot;:[{&quot;temp_filename&quot;:&quot;ff301078_input_14_o_1ad7pjak2psd8g4fhpi71ajia.jpg&quot;,&quot;uploaded_filename&quot;:&quot;test.jpg&quot;}]}">

Comment: I dont understand. Is it that you let the user upload any image but show only this image always in the preview or there is no option for the user to upload a image at all but you need to save this image against his record??

Comment: Thanks. there is no option for the user to upload a image at all.  but I need to save this image against his record??

Comment: Then there is no need for you to upload at all, You will show this preview all the time, then in your server you'll have to directly access the image from its path and use it the way you want. I dont think you have to send it back from your browser back to the server, Its not necessary